# Github download is deprecated

Tags: cdn, download, github

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

I'm using Github for a Open Source project, we have also used their file system so that users can download our binary installers and not just the source code.

But downloads are now deprecated https://github.com/blog/1302-goodbye-uploads

Whats the best free service for hosting downloads? Analytic features are a plus but not a requirement.

**Update:** Someone closed this question even though the linked question has nothing todo with Github. Anyway, the answer is that Github now support a feature called releases.

https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software